# What is a simple path in a directed graph?

Tags: graph-theory, definition

In graph theory, a simple path is a path that contains no repeated vertices. But, in a directed graph, the directions of the arrows must be respected, right? That is `A -> B <- C` is not a path? However, I have a source which states that would also be a simple path, but, according to the same source, that would not be a directed path. Why would `A -> B <- C` be considered a simple path, or is the source wrong? So, what is a simple path in a directed graph?

Comment: "A directed path in a digraph is a sequence of vertices in which there is a (directed) edge pointing from each vertex in the sequence to its successor in the sequence. A simple path is one with no repeated vertices."  https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/42digraph/

Comment: That definition *demands* that the path respect edge direction.  *Demands* it.

Comment: I think, read in context, the definition demands respecting edge direction.  Anyway... that's how I've always understood the term.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a quite universal consensus about the terminology here.

However, generally, most people would probably assume that when you have a *directed* graphs, the paths you're talking about will be directed path unless you're being quite explicit about ignoring the directionality.

I don't think just saying "simple" will be explicit enough to convey that. By that I would understand that the path cannot repeat vertices, but there's no reason such a path cannot be expected to respect the direction of edges -- so it makes plenty of sense to speak about *either* directed or undirected simple paths, and to implicitly assume the former when your edges happen to have direction.

If *you* want to speak about an undirected path in a directed graph, for the sake of communication please say "undirected path". If you need to decode something someone else says, you're at the mercy of their terminology. Ask for clarification if it is not clear what they mean.

Comment: Maybe you are familiar with causal inference and causality. If yes, in that context, would `A -> B <- C` be considered a simple path? In that context `A -> B <- C` is actually called a "collider". But I have a source which states that is also a simple path. I really don't get why, but, given the context I've just mentioned, maybe it makes sense. I don't know. Do you have any knowledge of causal inference?

Comment: @nbro: I refer you to my answer. "Simple" does not in my experience specify anything about whether the path respects directions or not, so I would not call an undirected path just a "simple path" when I'm talking about a directed graph.